# Type error while submitting custom udf with spark submit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Getting `TypeError` when submitting with spark-submit --py-files udf

`TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType`

I have written all the UDF`s in proj_udf.py

```
group_1 =['EAST','NORTH','SOUTH','SOUTHEAST','SOUTHWEST']
group_2 =['AUTORX','CAREWORKS','CHIROSPORT']

mearged_list = group_1 + group_2
str1 = ''.join(mearged_list)

def search_list(column):
    return any(column in item for item in str1)

sqlContext.udf.register("search_list_udf", search_list, BooleanType())
```

When calling this function from pyspark-shell its not throwing any error. When I run this with spark-submit getting following error.

Error:

```
  File "/hd_data/disk23/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hscrsawd/appcache/application_1530205632093_12027/container_1530205632093_12027_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/hd_data/disk23/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hscrsawd/appcache/application_1530205632093_12027/container_1530205632093_12027_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/hd_data/disk23/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hscrsawd/appcache/application_1530205632093_12027/container_1530205632093_12027_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 104, in <lambda>
    func = lambda _, it: map(mapper, it)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/hd_data/disk23/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hscrsawd/appcache/application_1530205632093_12027/container_1530205632093_12027_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 71, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "NAM_Udfs.py", line 115, in search_list
    return any(column in item for item in str1)
  File "NAM_Udfs.py", line 115, in <genexpr>
    return any(column in item for item in str1)
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your UDF to account for NULL's like below.  You might also want to account for empty strings in the column values.

```
def search_list(column):
    if column is None:
        return False
    return any(column in item for item in str1)
```